# Is it possible to set the values from one dictionary to another, without copying?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

```
d1 = <very_big_dictionary>

class DictLike(dict):
    ....

dict_like_object = DictLike(d1)
```

If I do this, then the values from d1 are being copied to the dict_like_object. But I DONT want the copy process. The d1 is enormously huge. I want that the internal dictionary of the newly created dict_like_object point to the key-values of d1. Is there some way of achieving dict_like_object to be the same object as d1, but also being a DictLike instance?

Comment: Why do you want that?

Comment: @KellyBundy I am using a library that extends dictionaries and ads functionalities. Basically they are models with getters and setters, but also keep beeing a  dict/json object.

Comment: Probably you should the build a `DictLike` in the first place instead of a normal `dict`.What does the library's documentation say? Also, how "enormously huge" is the dict?

Comment: @KellyBundy Huge means: there are around 34000 entries. Each entry is dict with ca 20 fields. One of the field is a list (10 to 100 entries) of dicts with 8 fields. I am receving those objects from an api once per second.

Comment: 34000 entries is rather *small* and I don't see a problem with your question's code.

Comment: @KellyBundy ok, i will... But is it possible?)

Comment: I don't know, since I don't know the library and the `DictLike` class. Maybe if it does something like `collections.ChainMap`? But again, what is the actual *problem* with your question's code? A dict with 34000 entries only needs about 1.3 MB memory, so I'm sure memory isn't the problem. What *is*?

Comment: @KellyBundy performance because of copying the dictionary by python. Python copy the dict, while DictLike(some_dictionary), and this is not necessary.

Comment: Is that really significant compared to building the dict in the first place and using it? With all that much bigger data inside? And just to be sure: you know that it does a *shallow* copy, right?